# Data is getting cut on page break and sometime repeats on new page while using jspdf and html2canvas

Tags: angular8, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using jspdf and html2canvas for generating multipage pdf. But the data gets cut off when new page starts. I cannot find any solution in the forums. Please help. Below is the code.

```
  let DATA = document.getElementById('Report');

  html2canvas(DATA).then(canvas => {

  var pageHeight;
  let fileWidth = canvas.width;
  let fileHeight = canvas.height * fileWidth / canvas.width;
  
  const FILEURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
  
  var top_left_margin = 15;
  var PDF_Width = fileWidth+(top_left_margin*2);
  var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width*1.5)+(top_left_margin*2);

  var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(fileHeight/PDF_Height)-1;
  let position = 0;
  var PDF = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',  [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
  PDF.addImage(FILEURI, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin,fileWidth,fileHeight);
 

  for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) { 
PDF.addPage("PDF_Width");

PDF.addImage(FILEURI, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),fileWidth,fileHeight);}
PDF.save('Report.pdf');
});
```